# Image File Download in ASP.Net C#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have written this code to download Images files. I think Code is working fine but when i opened downloaded image file in picasa it show (Invalid Image) all black , i have tried other windows tool to open file but no success.Path of the File is correct that i have checked. Path is Given in DataBase like: "~/New Images/Dir Sci/1.jpg"

```
        String[] path = Server.MapPath(filePath).Split('\\');    
        String FileName = path[path.Length - 1];    
        Response.ClearContent();    
        Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";    
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + FileName);    
        Response.TransmitFile(filePath);    
        Response.End();
```

This Code did not shown any error but when i debug this code using try catch and this exception came: {Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.}

Please Help Me Out.

Comment: You're using "filePath" and "FilePath" that we can't see defined. What are these and why are there 2?

Comment: Have you compared the downloaded file to the version on the server using, say, a hex editor?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're using the correct file name?  The best way to get the file name is to use the static Path.GetFileName(string) method, rather than manually splitting the path.

Also, the error about the native frames suggests you're debugging a Release build, not a Debug build (i.e. one that has been optimised).

Comment: File name and path is correct. I have checked it. I tried to create Bitmap img = new Bitmap(filePath); for checking, all image parameters are correct.